# prove inequality $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i+n)^2} < \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+n)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

How can I prove that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i+n)^2} < \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+n)^2}dx$$
where n is a natural number?

I mean, intuitive seems obvious, since the terms inside the expressions are positive and the sum "evaluates" less numbers, but how could I prove it rigorously?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I am trying to prove that the sum is less than 1/n

Comment: For the problem you want to get at, if you can use the result of the [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), you can shift the sum and have it be $\pi^2/6$ minus a term where [general Harminic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalization) might put you on track.

Comment: The problem is incorrect as stated: taking $n = 1$ gives $\pi^2/6$ for the sum and $1$ for the integral. The reverse inequality is true. Hint: for $x$ in the interval $(i,i+1)$, $\frac{1}{(i+n)^2} > \frac{1}{(x+n)^2}$, so $$\frac{1}{(i+n)^2} > \int_i^{i+1}\frac{1}{(x+n)^2} dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

To prove this, recall the definition of the [Riemann integral.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) Find the Riemann sum that approximates the integral.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality goes in the other direction, since the sum is an "oversum" of the integral.